# How should physical quantities transform under translation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, symmetry, tensor-calculus, covariance

I'm asking this question in the setting of non-relativistic classical mechanics.

We know that (consequence of the covariance principle?) physically meaningful quantities should be described by tensors, that is quantities that are invariant under rotation. Therefore, the components should obey well-known transformation rules.

What about translations? Different quantities transform differently under translations even if they transform in the same way under rotations. For example, positions are transformed and forces are invariant under rotation.

Are there transformation rules similar to what exists for tensors or is everything determined on a case-by-case basis?